# Creating new Cloud Run service revision via API

Tags: rest, google-cloud-run

Do I understand correctly that you cannot create a new Cloud Run service revision via the API ?

Looking under Revisions : https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.revisions : "Revisions are created by updates to a Configuration."

If we then check "Configurations" : https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.configurations : we only have a GET and a LIST method.

Answer (score 2):

It's not so hard, but you need to know well the Cloud Run service first. Cloud Run implement the [Knative API](https://knative.dev/) and one of the strength of Cloud Run is to guaranteed the portability on Cloud Run and on any K8S cluster that use Knative on top of it.

Thus,

- You have the [base URL](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest). Choose your region first.
- Then use the [create service URL for the creation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/create). You have to know that the `namespace_id` on Cloud Run managed is your `Project_ID`.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -X POST -d @knative.json \
  https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/<Project_ID>/services
```

- If you want to update the revision, use the [replace service API](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/replaceService). Same thing, but you need to add the name of the service in the URL and PUT it.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-type: application/json" \
  -X PUT -d @knative.json \
  https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/<Project_ID>/services/<ServiceName>
```

Because Cloud Run is compliant with Knative, the content of the file `knative.json` is a [Knative document](https://knative.dev/docs/serving/services/creating-services/) (in JSON in my example)

```
{
  "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
  "kind": "Service",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "<ServiceName>",
    "namespace": "<Project_ID>"
  },
  "spec": {
    "template": {
      "spec": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "image": "gcr.io/knative-samples/helloworld-go",
            "env": [
              {
                "name": "TARGET",
                "value": "Go Sample v2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note in this document the service Name and the Namespace (projectID) that you need to change.

Comment: Thank you! It's much more involved that I initially thought. Will try it out and report back :)